# How to debug VSCode extension with DevTools ?(Not just with VSCode itself)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I've followed the guide of VSCode extension devlopment (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/debugging-extensions), but I found no way to use Chrome DevTools to debug a VSCode extension. I want to use DevTool's Network Tab to debug network request from an extension.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks